# "'nullptr' was not declared in this scope" in GCC 7.5

Tags: pointers, gcc, compiler-errors

I am using GCC 7.5. When building packages, it complains about ordered comparison between integer and pointer, so I change the 0 in the comparison to nullptr.

But then I receive an error message that "'nullptr' was not declared in this scope".

Trying adding options -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 does not help.

All the programs are in C++.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it complains about ordered comparison between integer and pointer

"Ordered comparison" means comparison with `>` or `<` or `>=` or `<=`. It makes no sense to compare a pointer with a null pointer constant this way.

> so I change the 0 in the comparison to nullptr

This doesn't make the comparison any more meaningful. It makes no sense to compare a pointer with a null pointer constant this way either.

> But then I receive an error message that "'nullptr' was not declared in this scope".

This cannot happen with gcc 7.5 unless you

- compile C rather than C++ or
- pass `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++03` somewhere or
- have a broken installation of gcc.

In any case you probably want to fix the comparison (perhaps change `>` or `<` to `!=`) and only then think of maybe replacing `0` with `nullptr`.

Comment: There are no std options in the command line according the build log. Can it be the program is in C? Even if the file has extension .cpp? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Should I also change <=0 to =0?

Comment: I have no idea who would write a condition like `pointer <= 0` and why. This makes no sense whatsoever to me so I have no idea whether `== 0` or `!= 0` or anything else would be a good replacement (probably not). Perhaps ask a separate question about it and provide enough context.

Comment: So, I fixed the issues by removing ordered comparisons... Everything builds now, but I do not know if it will work.

Comment: To what should I change this? ``if (mixer_handle >= 0)``

Comment: No idea without context.

Comment: Can I simply disable this error message and make it compile things as in prevuous versions?

Comment: I guess so, but I would be very wary of any code that uses such comparisons.

Comment: ``alsa-sound.cpp:911:29: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope`` the file is cpp, as in other cases.

Comment: If you need further help, ask another question and provice a [mcve]. Clairvoyance is above my pay grade.